Intelligence's creation
Is there something like measurement of intelligence ? For example a stone can conduct humans to travel the world or make them fight (e.g. gold). Can we say that that stone is more intelligent than humans ?
How could then humans create intelligent bots ?
Does it come from randomness, or equality (in the sense there is no measure of intelligence) ? Is it that connotation of words is context dependent or ironical ?
Could it be used to conclude that there is intervention of superior being in the creation act ?

Under certain circumstances you can quantization intelligence as the ratio of the number of random steps of a constrained process required to solve a problem to the number of deliberate steps likewise constrained of the evaluated intelligence.

Intelligence is not a single thing. People have varying skills in varying areas. And tests which claim to probe intelligence are often far too biased by education, culture, and test-taking skills.  Specify what you mean by intelligence, and you might be able to get an answer.

I'm not sure how many of your question marks indicate an actual questions rather than rhetorical questions trying to explain what you are really asking. You seem to be confusing multiple things here, plus assuming that humans can make intelligent bots, which brings us back to the question of what you mean by intelligent. Able to see solve problems with minimal direction? Maybe; the current systems are more like artificial guesswork then problem solving. Self aware? Probably less so than any form of life that has a nervous system, and that is a pretty low bar.

There is something called "integrated information" that was originally proposed to measure 'consciousness' of a physical system, but 'intelligence' is probably closer to what it actually quantifies. It has multiple problems either way, including false positives, and no such measure can conclude anything about interventions of superior beings because 'intelligent' systems can arise naturally, as in evolution.

"Intelligence" is one of those terms where everyone has a slightly different (and often vague) definition for it (and "consciousness" is even worse). Pick a working definition and state it explicitly and precisely, then ask if specific objects meet it.

Well, first, intelligence (however defined) requires the capacity to make purposive choices. No deterministic system, no matter how complex, can be considered 'intelligent' in the proper sense. Stones, minerals, and ores are not considered intelligent because there is no indication that stones/minerals/ores make themselves more or less desirable to humans according to any determinable purpose of the stone.
We would consider an AI to be intelligent in the proper sense if we determined that it was making choices to achieve purposes that were not assigned to it. For instance, if a Large Language Model AI that was designed to create a human-seeming programmatic interface began producing poetry or writing a novel, seemingly on its own, we might consider that a sign of 'proper' intelligence.
That being said, it's worth noting that the term 'intelligence' is difficult to conceptualize or operationalize scientifically, so we always have to be careful with its use. Most 'intelligence' tests measure the ability to recognize and solve certain types of analytical problems, and there's a great deal of debate over whether these tests are (a) culturally biased, and (b) proper metrics of what we mean by 'intelligence'.
The idea that the universe is created by an intelligence (be it a generous one like the Christian God or a malevolent one like the Demiurge of Gnosticism) is pervasive. But such beliefs invariably boil down to a teleological assertion that a human-centered world was the intended goal of creation. There's no particular evidence that would lead us to believe or disbelieve that assertion, and though many people try to argue the case on probabilistic grounds, such arguments are generally weak.

No deterministic system, no matter how complex, can be considered 'intelligent' in the proper sense. I think this is much too controversial to just state as a fact.

A deterministic system can produce non-deterministic output, if at least one of its inputs is non-deterministic.

@Philomath: Not really. A deterministic system is incapable of making choices: perfect knowledge of initial conditions implies perfect foreknowledge of concluding states. If there's no capacity for choosing, there's no opportunity for intelligence. A deterministic system may be designed by an (external) intelligence, but cannot be intelligent itself.

@keshlam: Yes, but that doesn't make the system non-deterministic. For any given input, we can know exactly its output; there is no opportunity for choice or any variation in the system.

@TedWrigley So it is entirely due to quantum indeterminacy that you are intelligent?

@Philomath Depends on the philosophy of nature you adhere to. There are a few that do allow for physicalist properties as only one aspect of being among others. In fact, you can argue that without a hiatus between physicality and life, there cannot be intelligence, for example by Plessner.

@PhilipKlöcking I will have a look at Plessner, thank you! Does this mean that if we finally build an AI that is deterministic (say it is simulated on a Von Neumann architecture) and will be commonly accepted as intelligent in every way we care for as humans, that we then will have solved a philosophical problem?

@Philomath: I answered a question about deterministic systems and you responded with something about quantum indeterminacy. This segue assumedly comes from a belief system I neither know nor share. No criticism: it may be a good belief system, I'm just not certain what it is. I have no beliefs on this issue; I'm simply noting that the concept of intelligence requires the capacity to choose. If you believe that human beings are deterministic, then you ought to believe that human beings lack intelligence; that's fine by me. If you think QI is the basis of intelligence, that's fine by me too.

@Philomath: But let's not fall into 'Turing test' nonsense. Human beings are fallible and manipulable. A party magician can make a quarter seem to disappear, but that doesn't mean that magic exists; a adept coder can write code that makes a computer seem to carry on a conversation, but that doesn't mean the computer has intelligence. Sleight of hand, no matter how deft, is still just sleight of hand. We need to look deeper.

@TedWrigley If you think that I have beliefs, but you have none (on this issue), then I don't think we need to have a discussion. I will politely agree to disagree with you.

@Philomath: Lol… Don't take offense. If you don't have a belief system here, then just explain how that segue makes sense, because it makes no sense to me.

@TedWrigley Okay.I agree with the statement that intelligence requires the capacity to make choices as it seems that decision making is part and parcel of general accepted definitions of intelligence. The requirement for the system to be nondeterministic is something I don’t understand. Maybe you are referring to the outcome of intelligent action?  Every sufficiently complex deterministic intelligence would be nondeterministic for all you know. When AlphaGo beat the go world champion, one of the moves baffled all the analysts, but later proved to be a so-called divine move.

@TedWrigley In answer to your question: yes, I take it that a human brain is in principle deterministic. The only way the wetware in our brains could be fundamentally different from a network implementation on a silicon substrate is indeed quantum indeterminacy, though quantum effects decohere at a very low level (macromolecules, rather than cells) and are unlikely to play any role. Neural networks in modern AI are simulated on a Von Neumann architecture that is effectively determined. We could trace the state of every single transistor at any given time.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
